# Eclipse is not recognizing any error in Maven Project

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am writing some random lines but there is no error sign.
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is in `src/main/resource`s, which is marked as a resource directory. Code here doesn't get compiled. You'll want it to be in `src/main/java` if you want it compiled.

Comment: I was putting my code in (src/main/java) but it automatically shifted to (src/main/resources). Is there any way i can put it back to  (src/main/java) ? @tyrel

Comment: Just move it. Who has moved it to `src/main/resources`?

Comment: It sounds like you figured it out. Don't forget to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to configure [eclipsem2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) plugin in eclipse. Use below steps to create project with proper packaging :

1.Create Maven project

2.`Project-->right click-->Maven-->Update project configuration`

3.`Project-->right click-->Maven-->Update dependencies`

Also you can Use command   `mvn eclipse:eclipse -U` (it will generate .project, .classpath files and other configuration files)

Comment: I already have maven plugin and have done the above. Now my code is working, I have kept my code in the wrong folder. Thanks